# Set of template cals in java

Tags: java, templates, collections, set

I'm trying to create a Set that contains instances of 'Vertex3<T>'.  I'm having a little bit of an issue with the line that creates the set:

```
public Set<Vertex3<Integer>> verticies = new Set<Vertex3<Integer>>();
```

Eclipse is underlining in red the 'Set' part right of the equal sign, with the error message "**Cannot instantiate the type Set<Vertex3<Integer>>**".

'Vertex3<T>' is defined as follows:

```
public class Vertex3 <T> {
    public T x;
    public T y;
    public T z;

    public Vertex3() {
        // do nothing
    }

    public Vertex3(T x, T y, T z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public Vertex3(T x, T y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Any help that can be provided is appreciated.

Comment: All the answers are correct--you probably want a HashSet judging from your types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set is an interface, that's why you can't instantiate it. You have to instantiate a concrete Type, like HashSet (or TreeSet, or LinkedHashSet):

```
public Set<Vertex3<Integer>> verticies = new HashSet<Vertex3<Integer>>();
```

HashSet and LinkedHashSet store unique values... the performance of HashSet is better than LinkedHashSet, you probably want to use HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

Set is an interface just as the javadoc suggests: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html, thus it can not be instantiated

You should look at the `All Known Implementing Classes` and chose the implementation which suits you best and instantiate it with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Set is an interface. You cannot instantiate it. Replace the right part with either HashSet or TreeSet.